# Ubuntu 21.04 – make rectangular area screenshots by keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, mate, 21.04, shutter

I have used a keyboard short calling `shutter -s` and making an rectengular area screenshot under Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 for many years. No problems ever. Of course, shutter was already running... the redundant call would simply do it's job of captuing (and or tell the original instance, either way, no problem, proper capture, proper display in shutter window)[image]

Now, under Ubuntu-MATE 21.04 and with shutter 0.94.3 this is no longer working. Running `shutter -s` get's me:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/frank/snap/shutter/27/.config/gtk-`enter code here`2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini': File exists
Gtk-Message **: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module" at /snap/shutter/27/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Gtk2.pm line 126.
WARNING: gnome-web-photo is missing --> screenshots of websites will be disabled!


(shutter:74252): Unique-DBus-WARNING **: Error while sending message: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

INFO: There is already another instance of Shutter running!
```

- „screenshots of websites will be disabled“ has been around for years and should not be related
- not so sure what this symbolic link-warning is about...
- maybe the very last „INFO“ is a problem now, maybe it isn't?

What does work 90% of the time (as a script in keyboard shortcuts) is this workaround, but hey...

```
sh -c "killall shutter ; sleep .2; shutter --delay=2 -s &"
```

#### ... ist there a better way to do this? Or a known bug on shutter's end?

(there were some suggestions out there to use `shutter -s -e`, but it is not helping)

Comment: The current version of `Shutter` on my MATE 21.04 instance is v0.97 (Rev.1549) The odd thing is though, I don't seem able to set a shortcut for it but the shortcut is in the top panel anyway.

Comment: Indeed today there has been an update to `Shutter` in both MATE 21.04 and ubuntu 20.04 instances to v0.98 (Rev 1570). You might wish to run `Software Updater` to get it and then try again.

Comment: Thank you, @24601. (Post you answer and I will accept it)

Comment: Done - thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Credits go to @24601 for his comment above (post an answer, 24601, and I will accept it)

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -q -y shutter
```

Indeed I upgrade from 0.94.3 to 0.98 Rev.1570 and the problem is: GONE. → `shutter -s` in any command line terminal, as often as you like... all working nicely.

Also better highDPI support even on first sight... (larger fonts and image display on 4K monitors...)

**Update:** Sadly still plenty of problems. Grabs a rectangular area, but at a completely wrong offset... :/  I have triple screen (native laptop, 4K high dpi display, 4K high dpi display) – possibly this is not correctly adressed...

Comment: As for me, Shutter is overkill. On the Ubuntu MATE you can simply press `Shift`+`PrintScreen` and then select rectangular zone using default MATE Screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of `Shutter` on my MATE 21.04 instance was v0.97 (Rev.1549) The odd thing is though, I don't seem able to set a shortcut for it but the shortcut is in the top panel anyway.

Indeed there has since been an update to Shutter in both MATE 21.04 and ubuntu 20.04 instances to v0.98 (Rev 1570). You might wish to run Software Updater to get it and then try again.

Comment: I have constant problem seeing it in the top-panel as well (after starting, after taking a screenshot, killing, restarting shutter)...

Comment: There was a further update today (11Aug21) (although still at v0.98 Rev. 1570)